# PorterStemmer in Lucene

Tags: lucene, indexing, stemming, porter-stemmer

I am looking for help on how I can use the class PorterStemFilter in Lucene 4.0. Below is my indexer taken from http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-in-5-minutes.html:

...

```java
  StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_40);
  Directory index = new RAMDirectory();
  IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_40, analyzer);

  IndexWriter w = new IndexWriter(index, config);
  addDoc(w, "Lucene in Action", "193398817");
  addDoc(w, "Lucene for Dummies", "55320055Z");
```

......

Could someone help me with where and how to use the [PorterStemFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/en/PorterStemFilter.html) class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filters are generally incorporated into an [Analyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer.html).  To create you own Analyzer, the only thing you really need to override is the `TokenStream` method.

If you just want to chuck a the stem filter into StandardAnalyzer, I would copy the implementation of `tokenStream` from StandardAnalyzer, and add the filter at the appropriate location (with stemmers, usually they should be added late in the filter chain).

```java
@Override
public TokenStream tokenStream(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
    StandardTokenizer tokenStream = new StandardTokenizer(Version.LUCENE_46, reader);
    tokenStream.setMaxTokenLength(255);
    TokenStream result = new StandardFilter(tokenStream);
    result = new LowerCaseFilter(result);
    result = new StopFilter(true, result, StopAnalyzer.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS_SET);
    //Adding the StemFilter here
    result = new PorterStemFilter(result);
    return result;
}
```

Alternatively, you could just use [`EnglishAnalyzer`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/en/EnglishAnalyzer.html) (among [other languages](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/overview-summary.html)), which already has a stemmer.

Comment: I don't really need to create my own Analyzer if they already handle Filters. But, I was wondering why I am not getting hits for queries like 'country'. I can get hits for the query 'countires'.

Comment: Not sure I understand... So you have documents with "countries", and want a query for "country" to find them?  Yes, that would be an appropriate time to use a stemmer.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I wanted. I am using StandardAnalyzer as my analyzer and Lucene version 4.6. If stemmer is incorporated in the analyzer, why is it failing to retrieve documents when the query is 'country'?

Comment: No, there is no stemming in `StandardAnalyzer`.  Use `EnglishAnalyzer` (link in the answer above).